# Database: what is tie scheme?

Tags: database

I'm learning Introduction to Database Systems[BerkeleyX: CS W186] and I'm confused by one practice:

```
Which scheme will be faster for inserting a key (e.g. 4.5)?
1. Heap File [Right answer]
2. Sorted File
3. Tie
```

I know heap file and sorted file are both database file structure, but what tie scheme is?

Comment: It is asking if it a tie (also known as a draw) in terms of performance - it could be rewritten as `3. Will options 1 and 2 be the same speed?`

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know English option 3 mean answers 1 and 2 are equally fast

Comment: Got it. Thank you!